# Keep middle div in slider highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a "product" slider called lightSlider(http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/), which I want to behave a bit differently compared to the original version.

My slider looks like this at the moment: 
[Link to screenshot - current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t28rD.jpg).
I would like to highlight the second div(the middle div) and if clicking on next(right/left arrow) then I still want the middle div highlighted as shown here:
[Link to screenshot - goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9K0Y.jpg)

I would like it to be done in javascript/jQuery. But I have no idea where to start with the javascript/jQuery since I still consider myself a beginner.

Comment: can you post your code...

Comment: You can see the code I'm using here, its the red slider(below the slider with birds): http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript or jquery for this one. If you see inspect the element [i used the examples of the `lightslider` on github], they add an `active` class to the first element of the current view.

So you can simply add a CSS to achieve what you want.

`li.item-c.lslide.active + li {
   // your highlight css properties
}`

Comment: Smart thinking, I almost forgot all about adjacent sibling selectors. It works. Thank you for your help Jayendra!